# update a table where comparing 4 variables?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to update the validated column on the table by comparing the 4 fields with the 4 variables

Here is sample code

```
$query1 = mysql_query("UPDATE tbl_grades_subj 
                      SET activated01 = 1 
                      WHERE grades_subject_code = '$hidden_subj1' 
                      & grades_term = '$hidden_term1' 
                      & section = 'hidden_sec1' 
                     & grades_sy = 'hidden_sy1'")
           or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: MySQL uses `AND`, not `&`.

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is incorrect. You need to use `AND` and not `&` in your `WHERE` clause.

```
WHERE grades_subject_code = '$hidden_subj1' 
AND grades_term = '$hidden_term1' 
AND section = 'hidden_sec1' 
AND grades_sy = 'hidden_sy1'
```

Comment: i try &,&&,AND but still no update, is it possible to compare the data inside a database with 4 or more variables?

Comment: Yes. This means the data you have in your database isn't what you're expecting it to be.

Comment: when i try updating using 1 variable to compare with, it update the data, but when i update using 4 variables nothing happens.

Comment: It's not the quantity of conditions that is the problem. One or more of your conditions are false. You need to figure out which one(s) and why that is the case. Your query is otherwise perfectly fine.

Comment: got it, appreciated all the response guys! thanks!

Answer (score 2):

use `AND` instead of `&`. `&` does bit-wise AND, you want a LOGICAL and.

```
... WHERE field=X and field=Y AND field=z etc...
```

Comment: id try this but still no update! 
$query1 = mysql_query("UPDATE tbl_grades_subj SET activated01 = 1
             WHERE grades_subject_code = '$hidden_subj1' 
             AND grades_term = '$hidden_term1' 
             AND section = 'hidden_sec1' 
             AND grades_sy = 'hidden_sy1'");

Comment: then check that you actually have records which those conditions.